# How do you use custom keys inside of firebase .update method?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

When I try to assign a key to in a multi-path .update() like this:

```
key1 = 'bar';
key2 = 'baz';

db.ref('path').update({
                key1: 'value1',
                key2: 'value2'});
```

It literally writes the key as a string to the DB:

```
/path/key1/value1
/path/key2/value2
```

**QUESTION:** how can I get the expected output with dynamic keys?

```
/path/bar/value1
/path/baz/value2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the expected output, you need to use brackets around your **[keys]**:

```
key1 = 'bar';
key2 = 'baz';

db.ref('path').update({
                [key1]: 'value1',
                [key2]: 'value2'});
```

This will give you:

```
/path/bar/value1
/path/baz/value2
```